# Issue with ImageMagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

im struggling with something simple as reading an image in ImageMagick and not sure why

The website is hosted under linux PHP version 5.4

After uploading the image i do this in order to print it.

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$imagen = new Imagick($image);
$imagen->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
echo $image;
```

**(pub1.gif) it's the name of the original image to be uploaded**

But i'm getting the following error and no idea how to handle it.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'unable to open image `pub1.gif': No such file or directory @
>   blob.c/OpenBlob/2480' in
>   /home/content/38/10882038/html/carsventa/accountpass/post/publish-advertisement.php:74Stack
>   trace:#0
>   /home/content/38/10882038/html/carsventa/accountpass/post/publish-advertisement.php(74):
>   Imagick->__construct('pub1.gif')#1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/content/38/10882038/html/carsventa/accountpass/post/publish-advertisement.php
>   on line 74

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should be using:**

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

instead of:

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

You're trying to use the client file, that is not located in your server, therefore the library cannot access it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The global `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the original filename, not the file on disk. The uploaded image is in a temp file under `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, which will be deleted on script completion. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```php
 $image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $imagen = new Imagick($image);
 $imagen->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
 echo $image;
```